# How to find all functions $a, b, c$ of $t$ that satisfy $ a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = k, k \in \mathbb{R}^+$

Tags: functions

If $a(t), b(t), c(t) $ are continuous functions of $ t $, then find all possible candidates for $a(t), b(t), c(t) $ such that $ [a(t)]^2 + [b(t)]^2 + [c(t)]^2 = k$, where $k \in \mathbb{R}^+$.

What's a good way to systematically solve this problem? Of course, I can guess at some functions that would definitely satisfy the equation--letting $ a(t), b(t), c(t) $ all be constants. Also, letting $ a(t) = \cos t, b(t) = \sin t, c(t) = 0 $ or some permutations of that also work. I could even make each one a function of two variables or three variables if I wanted, to make polar or spherical coordinate substitutions. But that doesn't really help. Any hints or methods I could use to make this easier?

Comment: There is far more of these functions than you probably realize. If you pick $a(t)$ to be _any_ function satisfying $|a(t)|<\sqrt{k}$, then picking $b(t)=0,c(t)=\sqrt{k-a(t)^2}$ will do, and this is still _far_ from being all functions. There is no simple parametrization of any sort.

Comment: You haven’t said anything about your functions being required to be continuous.

Comment: @Lubin good point, I have updated the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you want $k > 0$.  Geometrically, $(a(t),b(t),c(t))$ is a parametric representation of an arbitrary curve on the sphere of radius $\sqrt{k}$ centred at the origin.

Comment: Yes, $k \geqslant 0$

Answer (score 1):

$a^2+b^2+c^2=R^2$ is a sphere in dimension $3$ centered in $(0,0,0)$ of radius $R$ so you might want to switch to spherical coordinates.

$\begin{cases}
a(t)=\sqrt{k}\cos(\theta(t))\sin(\phi(t)) \\
b(t)=\sqrt{k}\cos(\theta(t))\sin(\phi(t)) \\
c(t)=\sqrt{k}\cos(\phi(t))
\end{cases}$

Depending on the functions $\theta(t),\phi(t)$ this gives you any curve on the sphere.

Answer (score 0):

We can "parameterise" the solution set, but with function-valued parameters instead of number-valued ones. Let $f,\,g$ denote arbitrary functions of modulus $\le 1$. Set $a=\sqrt{k}f,\,b=\sqrt{k-a^2}g$. This determines $h:=|c|$. Then $c=hj$ for some arbitrary $j$ that is always $\pm 1$.